# scraping with selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am scraping urls of this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2019-2020/results/

For each urls like this https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2019-2020/cska-moscow-fc-tambov/8Ya3mpOC/
I want scrape bet365 opening odds and i use this part of code

```
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/span").click()
        sleep(3)
        homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]').text
        print (homeodd)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        homeodd = 'No odds found'
        print(homeodd)
```

With this code i can scrape what i wish but when i try with  X , 2 opening odds i have blank results

```
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[5]/span").click()
        sleep(3)
        drawodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]').text
        print (drawodd)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        drawodd = 'No odds found'
        print(drawodd)
```

Also in some pages there are not popups for scraping odds and i tried with this part of code

```
else:
     homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/span").text
     print (homeodd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your XPath expressions. Use `findElement` for the first 3. `findElements` for the last.

To get the home odd :

```
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][1]/span
```

To get the draw odd :

```
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][2]/span
```

To get the away odd :

```
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][3]/span
```

To get them all :

```
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span]/span
```

Getting them all is probably better since you call `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` 1 time. For each match, store each element of the result (a list) in your specific lists (append the first in the home odd list, the second in the draw odd list, the third in the away odd list).

**EDIT** : To get the opening odds, extract the value from the attribute `data-opening-odd`. XPath :

```
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][1]/@data-opening-odd
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][2]/@data-opening-odd
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][3]/@data-opening-odd
//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span]/@data-opening-odd
```

Selenium syntax :

```
awayodd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][3]'))).get_attribute("data-opening-odd")
```

Comment: These xpath scrape closing odds, i would opening odds that are in a popup. How could i change those xpath? I tried this

`//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]/following-sibling::td[span][2]/span
`