# web scraping with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I would scrape opening odds in this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league/results/
I tried this code:

```
   try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[span]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        homeodd = 'no bet365 odd'
        drawodd = 'no bet365 odd'
        awayodd = 'no bet365 odd'
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]").click()
        sleep(3)
        homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[ends-with(@id,'16')]//tr[th='Opening odds']/following-sibling::tr/td[@class='bold']").text
        print(homeodd)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[5]").click()
        sleep(3)
        drawodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[ends-with(@id,'16')]//tr[th='Opening odds']/following-sibling::tr/td[@class='bold']").text
        print(drawodd)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[6]").click()
        sleep(3)
        awayodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[ends-with(@id,'16')]//tr[th='Opening odds']/following-sibling::tr/td[@class='bold']").text
        print(awayodd)
```

I have this error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//table[ends-with(@id,'16')]//tr[th='Opening odds']/following-sibling::tr/td[@class='bold']' is not a valid XPath expression.
However i wrong xpath syntax.

The problem is that in this page there is no attribute `data-opening-odd`. I asked in this previous post for another [scraping with selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303040/scraping-with-selenium-web-driver) and with a great suggestion of the community i found this great solution

```
try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[span]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        homeodd = 'no bet365 odd'
        drawodd = 'no bet365 odd'
        awayodd = 'no bet365 odd'
    else:
        homeodd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][1]'))).get_attribute("data-opening-odd")
        drawodd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][2]'))).get_attribute("data-opening-odd")
        awayodd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[a[.="bet365"]]/following-sibling::td[span][3]'))).get_attribute("data-opening-odd")
```

Any suggestion to adapt the second solution without get the odds from the attribute `data-opening-odd`? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One easy solution is to use a software called Parse Hub : https://www.parsehub.com/quickstart

You can **scrape** data of any website using it! Its really easy to use If you need any help using it just tell me and ill help you out but I think a YouTube tutorial might be just about enough to learn how to use it!